# "Literally" convert string to bytearray in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin, byte

I've got a string that looks like this:

```
val something = "-90, -91, 0, -38, 83, 110, etc..."
```

I then split it by commas and get:

```
val parts = [-90, -91, 0, -38, 83, 110, etc...]
```

How can I convert this to a ByteArray in Kotlin? Do Kotlin have anything similiar to Python's `bytes.fromhex()`?

I've tried

```
ByteArray(parts.size){ parts[it].trim().toByte() }
```

, but I seem to be getting weird characters like @. Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're doing it correctly. Arrays don't have a nice `toString()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ByteArray cannot be displayed directly with print. That weird characters with @ is the storage location.

But you can iterate over the array like this:

```
val result = ByteArray(split.size){ split[it].trim().toByte() }

for (byte: Byte in result) {
   println(byte)
}
```

Or more functional:

```
result.forEach{ println(it) }
```

Output as Hex value:

```
for (b in result) {
    val st = String.format("%02X", b)
    println(st)
}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can display it correctly with print?

Comment: You may convert it `.toList()`